# Find and access specific DIV so I can append content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find and access a div on the click of a button but I'm not being able to find out the DIV based on the button I clicked.

I know I have to use parent, or siblings stuff like that... but I'm kinda lost on this one and would appreciate any help.

This is the html structure

```
    <div class="box" id="upcoming">
        <div class="box-head">
            <header><h4>Test Header</h4></header>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="widget-upcoming">
                <div class="test">
                    Hello
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer"><button type="button" class="btn load-more">LOAD MORE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the jquery I have so far is:

```
    $(".load-more").on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).parent().html());
    });
```

This is showing the content of box-footer. I'm not figuring it out how to get to the widget-upcoming DIV, that's where I'm going to append other DIVs together with the .test one

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
$(".load-more").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.box').find('.widget-upcoming').html());
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/x5jku7fp/)

Note: There are another ways, but I think that this is the easiest.